# How do you calculate sample difference in terms of sensor signals?

Tags: feature-selection, data-cleaning

A paper I read called *Preprocessing Techniques for Context Recognition from  Accelerometer Data* refers to sample difference as the delta value between signals in a pairwise arrangement of samples that allows a basic comparison between the intensity of user activity.

How would you do the pairwise arrangement? Would it require you to have different files of data representing different classes?

For example, I have a CSV:

```
 1495573445.162, 0, 0.021973, 0.012283, -0.995468, 1
 1495573445.172, 0, 0.021072, 0.013779, -0.994308, 1
 1495573445.182, 0, 0.020157, 0.015717, -0.995575, 1
 1495573445.192, 0, 0.017883, 0.012756, -0.993927, 1
```

where the second, third, and fourth columns are the axes of accelerometer data.

I have several files named for one gesture and several others for another gesture and would like to use this sample difference statistic to help classify the data.

Also as a secondary question, this was listed as a preprocessing technique but it sounds like it's more of a feature. Could I get clarification on that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differencing is a common preprocessing step for time series. Here's an example in python:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
data=[[1495573445.162, 0, 0.021973, 0.012283, -0.995468, 1],
 [1495573445.172, 0, 0.021072, 0.013779, -0.994308, 1],
 [1495573445.182, 0, 0.020157, 0.015717, -0.995575, 1],
 [1495573445.192, 0, 0.017883, 0.012756, -0.993927, 1]]
df = DataFrame(data, columns=['timestamp', 'foo', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'bar']).set_index('timestamp')
df.assign(dx=df.x.diff(), dy=df.y.diff(), dz=df.z.diff())
```

The result:

```
               foo         x           y            z   bar        dx         dy          dz
timestamp                               
1.495573e+09    0   0.021973    0.012283    -0.995468   1         NaN        NaN         NaN
1.495573e+09    0   0.021072    0.013779    -0.994308   1   -0.000901   0.001496    0.001160
1.495573e+09    0   0.020157    0.015717    -0.995575   1   -0.000915   0.001938   -0.001267
1.495573e+09    0   0.017883    0.012756    -0.993927   1   -0.002274  -0.002961    0.001648
```

Comment: When I set data to the values from your list, I get your output. However, when I read from my file using `pandas.read_csv(filename)`, I get NaN for every value in each column.

Comment: The sample csv you gave loaded fine with read_csv; I just set `header=None`. Can you read any csv?

Comment: Something else must be going on because after I do `data = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=None)` followed by `df = pandas.Dataframe(data, , columns=['timestamp', 'time skipped', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'label']).set_index('timestamp')` and `return df`, I get NaN as well.

Comment: I don't get a data frame filled with `NaN` if I only do `df = pandas.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: Once you have data as a DataFrame you don't need df. My `data` is a nested list. Please complete [the pandas tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't realized that `read_csv()` returns a DataFrame.